# App runs in VS iis express but not in IIS 8 (v2)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I have no luck with MVC running on IIS on Windows 2019, even trying a new VS generated test site.

The application run ok using `IIS Express`, as *https://localhost:44358* but fail on IIS.

On the master web, I `add application..` using IIS Manager,  alias and a physical path.
The application fail to start.
I was able to trace some code and IIS went pass registering routes failing later with:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

then a brief html code from

```
Source File: C:\inetpub\<redacted>\Views\Shared\_Layout.vbhtml    Line: 40


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_vbhtml.Execute() in C:\inetpub\<redacted>\Views\Shared\_Layout.vbhtml:40
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +90
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<RenderPageCore>b__0(TextWriter writer) +232
...
```

referencing *`@Html.ActionLink`*.
Next, I tried to run it as a web site: on IIS Manager, `Add Website`, filling  *site*, *physical path* and a *host name*, with the same identical result.
I suspect that the dll that defines @Html.ActionLink is no properly loaded, buy no clue how to check or fix.

**Full Source**

> There are a few function used here defined elsewhere, working as intended.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @code
        Tell(True, $"_Layout. {TraceBack()}")
    End Code

    <!-- Must run in a domain logged pool with SQL access -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title </title>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fajs")
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")

    <style type="text/css">

        td {
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        .absolute-bottom {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="m-1 p-1">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" style="border:0px transparent;">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <i class="fas fa-home" style="width:2em;color: Dodgerblue;"></i>
                        Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Intranet")
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fas fa-ice-cream" style="width:2em;color: Dodgerblue;"></i>
                        Html.ActionLink("Icons", "Icons", "Intranet")
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fas fa-money-bill" style="width:2em;color: Dodgerblue;"></i>
                        Html.ActionLink("Deals", "Deals", "Intranet")
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fas fa-concierge-bell" style="width:2em;color: Dodgerblue;"></i>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Intranet")
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fas fa-address-book" style="width:2em;color: Dodgerblue;"></i>
                        @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Intranet")
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Identity: @WebIdentity.Name @WebIdentity.AuthenticationType @WebIdentity.User.Value</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <footer class="card-footer align-bottom">
            <p class="text-center text-capitalize">

                &copy; <redacted> @DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
                @WebDomain\@WebUserName
                <!-- (@WindowsIdentity.Name) @WebIdentity.AuthenticationType @WebIdentity.IsAuthenticated -->
            </p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required:=False)

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('*[data-autocomplete-url]')
                .each(function () {
                    $(this).autocomplete({
                        source: $(this).data("autocomplete-url")
                    });
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

✔**NOTE**
Due the asynchronous work inside the IIS and MVC engine, the diagnostic message was misleading.
The error was inside one of my own support routines.
When processing @html.ActionLink(.....) one of my classes was used before it was properly instantiated.

I will delete this question is a few days. Thanks!!

Comment: you can check your bin folder to see if all dll's are loaded properly. If something is missing, just rebuild and publish to IIS folder

Comment: I assume the bin folder is the same on both cases (there are almost 200 files there). I also tried to run it directly from the development path with no avail.

Comment: the corresponding dll is `System.Web.Mvc.dll`. check if it exists

Comment: share the Layout page.

Comment: @LinkedListT the page is the default page plus a few @@html.ActionLink (Web.Mvc.Html), if I comment them, the problem goes up to @@Styles (Web.Optimization) commenting Styles, fail on @@Scripts!

Comment: not enough info. Show Layout or wherever it's breaking. Looks like _Layout.vbhtml ln4 (and ln40). Also is the Html.ActionLInk in layout?

Comment: I copied a running MVC app and replaced routes, (M)odels (V)iews and (C)ontrolers, reinstalled a few Nuget packages, added my shared code and now is up and running.

Comment: is your issue is resolved? If your issue is solved then I request you to post the solution and mark it as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I will love to do it but... was just an issue unrelated to MVC or ASP. Basically my own routine was using a non-instantiated class. It's a very bad example. I think will be a waste of other pals time to read me. That class was not used when running on IIS Express: that was the issue that point to the wrong conclusion.  But yes, to create a new app and copy the files from the old helped a lot in finding the culprit.